3 EVALSTPM34 boards connected by 1 Clk source work unstable
I am trying to test STPM34 chip by using its EVAL board by ST. I have 3 of these boards because idea is to use 3 of them for different 220 V and current measurements. Datasheet states that it is possible to use 1 Oscillator for clock and use output of Clkout to clock up to 2 chips:

did jus that and after running example code I started to notice, that voltage and other readings began to be unstable. I am testing it with 7 V rms signal and most of the time I see this voltage read from registers, but sometimes it changes to random value (30, 0, 1000 etc.). I tried reinstalling original oscillators and it worked perfectly without random values, so I guess it has something to do with clk of whole chip. What could be the problem here? I checked signals on CLKOUT and CLKIN and well it seems OK,I get 16 MHz signal.
EDIT: I am using SPI interface for all 3 boards, auto latching (SYN pin is used only for restarting the board). I also tried different SPI clock speeds but had no luck. I read registers at a frequency of 1 Hz  (sampling frequency and auto latching frequency of STPM34 is 7.8125 KHz)

Without having referred to the datasheet, I’d suggest there is a specified capacitive load and that you are exceeding this. It could simply be the length of your wires/pcb tracks. I would suggest that if your aim is to have synchronous sampling of the inputs that you quantify what might be an acceptable timing error that would not impact your application unduly and to use a common gpio to communicate a timing reference. This is most likely a more robust solution vs tying the clocks together as this would only guarantee synchronicity if each micro executed the same code sequences.

well my application needs as less gpio used as possible, so I'm trying everything that  manufacturer suggests. This diagram is from datasheet and no length of traces (wires) recommendations are provided, dev board has headers with CLKIN and CLKOUT so I assume that it is possible to chain each board with regular wire.

Wrong assumption. The chips doesn't care about how a user manual for a dev board is worded, or what you assume - they just see the load they see, and for clocks there are indeed requirements for the clock line capacitance that need to be fulfilled. See the chip datasheet for max capacitive load and flank requirements on clock pins. They need to be fulfilled, no matter what.
